# Change datepicker bootstrap margin from field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the margin of the date-picker's text field.

[image: date-picker]

What i want, is to make date-picker look like in this picture

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rishita-parmar : i've change margin-top in css code but nothing has changed. but now I know why. it is because editable css. datepicker class is also defined in css code editable. problem solved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the margin of the `.datepicker` element, e.g.:

```
.datepicker {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Change the `5px` to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the margin-top of the data-picker class. If yo don't know exactly the class try using the [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [firefox dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), accordingly to your favorite web browser.